# WPF - How do I sort a DataGridTemplateColumn with a list of strings as content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have the following code:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredLectureViewModels}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <!-- Profs -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Profs">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:LectureViewModel">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Profs}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProfString}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I want the datagrid to sort its content by clicking on the header 'Profs' like it's working for a DataGridTextColumn with the header 'Name' already by default. I know the attribute 'SortMemberPath' of the DataGridTemplateColumn, but i don't know how to use that in this situation.

Comment: What sorting behavior do you want when the user clicks on the `Name` column?

Comment: The sorting behavior of the Name column is fine, it's sorting the items alphabetically depending on their Name.
What I want is a sorting behavior by clicking on the Profs column. It should sort the items according to the ProfString of the first prof in the Profs-List.
Sorry for my not so perfect english ^^

Comment: Oops, that was my mistake, I asked about the `Name` column but what I meant was the `Profs` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bindings, you can use brackets `[` `]` to supply an index for a collection as part of the binding path. Upon testing, this same approach seems to work for `SortMemberPath`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Profs" SortMemberPath="Profs[0].ProfString">
```

This sorts based on the `ProfString` property of the first item in `Profs`. I'm not sure *why* you would want to sort based on the first item in a collection, but this does it.

Comment: That works! Nice, thank you.
It's very rare that the collection Profs has more than 1 item, so I'm fine with sorting it based on the first Item.